# How to implement a pandas dataframe row as an object (and have its own methods)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using a pandas dataframe to hold financial data (time series of candlesticks).

**Columns are:** *(index: datetime, financial_instrument, granularity, open, high, low, close, volume).*

I have built a class that stores this dataframe to implement specific methods for this kind of object (time series of candlesticks), such as:

```
def getCandle(self, i):
    try:
        return self._list_of_candles.iloc[i:]
    except:
        return None

def getLastCandle(self):
    return self.getCandle(-1)

def getPreviousCandle(self):
    return self.getCandle(-2)
```

It makes a lot of sense for me to think as each row on the dataframe as an object (candlestick), and to have specific methods for this object, such as:

```
def getCandleSize(self):
    return self.getHighValue() - self.getLowValue()
```

I am open to completely different lines of thought on how to deal with this problem and how to architecture its solution.

I honestly have no clue on how to solve it. The solution I can see now is by implementing some specific methods on top of the pandas series object. But how to implement it is not clear to me.

Once the row (candle) is selected from the dataframe, it can be manipulated quite a lot, so in previous applications I had built, it was really useful to have a 'Candle' class for these kinds of operations.

I need a performant solution. I really appreciate if you can point me in the direction of a solution for this problem. Thank you.

**UPDATE:** I am thinking about converting the selected row to a Candle object, as it seems much easier to build code if it is structured that way, as I don't need to be making fecthing data from the dataframe for each atributte or calculation to be made.

Comment: why do you need to do this? `candle_size = df['high'] - df['low']` will just work on all of the rows at once

Comment: What type of methods are you trying to use? If you're just trying to pull up the candelstick before the index you're currently looking at why not use: candles.iloc[i-1]

Comment: @Paul I am thinking about your proposed solution. Right of the bat, each dataframe has up to 10M rows, and I won't need to do these kinds of calculations for most of the rows, just for a few select ones. 

Hadn't thought about it that way, I appreciate your input and it might work, I will test to see how long it takes to make the calculations.

Comment: @joaoavf the pass `df.loc[row_selection, 'high'] - df.loc[row_selection, 'low']` where `row_selection` is something that limits the calculation to "just the select ones" you want.

Comment: @TheSaint321 I basically need to access the candle's attributes quite frequently. It is useful to have some built in methods to the simpler calculations like date manipulation and simple sum and subtractions that makes a lot of sense to be read as methods.    candles.iloc[i-1] works but it doesn't give me the easeness of having methods which are specific to manipulate the resulting object.

Comment: @juanpa thank you. It does work, but I do have quite a few different results that I might want from a specific row, and it is looking a lot easier to convert the row to a Candle object to be manipulated later.